# Issues with importing views functions in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have made a function in my views.py  and i want to use this function in forms.py of another application.
I did this successfully at my local server and when i try to implement same at live server ,I got the internal server error,But if i import the same function in some other file say views.py it works.
And if i import the view function of same application in that forms.py I got the same error.

So i am confused how it works in local and not in live .

The version of python in my local system is 2.6 and at live is 2.7 , is this possible that it may occurs errors.

Thanks.

Edited:

**views.py**

```
def pass_update(login_info):
   some code
```

now in my forms.py i want to use this function so that i can send the required data to this.
but when i use this **from invites.views import pass_update**  I got the internal server error.
But in my local same code works

Comment: a traceback of the error would also be usefull

Comment: @zepatou  as i said i got the internal server error so i there is no traceback of the error

Comment: I never tried this one ever since because probably I will get an error. Why not use it views to views than views to form?

Comment: But in forms.py any view function i tried to import , I got the errors  , but in my local it works. It looks that i cannot import any view function on live , But how it works at local , I am also using different versions of python , is this the issue